# new nodes created where start elasticsearch in kubernetes

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I'm using `elasticsearch 2.4.1` and `kubernetes 1.9.2`. My `es` path.data directory is mounted by nfs, two nodes are sharing the data. When I restart the `es` (restart deployment in k8s), 2 new nodes are created for sometime,  0 and 1 is old, 2 and 3 are created after restart. Why can't the `es` server recognize the old nodes?

```
root@elasticsearch-logging-686b8f5f95-lp9xh:/data/kubernetes-logging/nodes# ls -l

total 0

drwxr-xr-x 3 elasticsearch elasticsearch 37 Mar  4 09:04 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 elasticsearch elasticsearch 37 Mar  4 09:04 1
drwxr-xr-x 3 elasticsearch elasticsearch 37 Mar  5 06:39 2
drwxr-xr-x 3 elasticsearch elasticsearch 37 Mar  5 06:39 3
```

Comment: What do you mean by "restart es nodes", are you merely restarting the deployment? Also can you post what commands you are using?

Comment: yes,  stop by "kubectl scale deploy elasticsearch-logging -n kube-system --replicas=0" , after pods are deleted and start by "kubectl scale deploy elasticsearch-logging -n kube-system --replicas=2"